# Error: the call causes portability problems because it has different locales

Tags: java, error-handling, fortify

The full error: The call causes portability problems because it has different locales which may lead to unexpected output. This may also circumvent custom validation routines.

Running a tool over my code I get this issue depending on this part of my code:

```
 if ("paid".equals(type.toLowerCase())) {
        return PaymentType.PAID.getDescription();
    }
```

I don't really understand what the problem should be with this code here?

Comment: I think you should provide more context info on what's the call, how and where it's being called etc. since currently it's really difficult to see the whole picture

Comment: "a tool" - why not tell us which one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `toLowerCase()` and `toUpperCase()` methods use the default locale. This can give different results depending on the locale and the characters in the string you're converting. It's kinda like the default encoding problem (except less likely to bite you in the ass, unless you're working with uncommon characters).

You can avoid the warning by explicitly specifying `toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH)` or just use `"paid".equalsIgnoreCase(type)`.

Comment: I googled a bit more and this seems to be the right answer to it thanks a lot

Comment: I don't understand why using equalsIgnoreCase makes a difference.  What's going on behind the scenes?  Also I've seen some pages that say equalsIgnoreCase shouldn't be used when comparing non-English words.  Is that the same type of portability problem that we're trying to solve here?

Comment: @stackhouse it makes the warning go away, which was the main point. The `equalsIgnoreCase()` javadoc warns that it does not take locale into account too (making it unsuitable for some kinds of text work), but in this case it doesn't matter.

Comment: can you give an example on uncommon way?